# Is it at all possible to extend System.Delegate?

Tags: delegates, cil

It is not possible to inherit from System.Delegate or System.MulticastDelegate in C#. It is perfectly possible to do it in MSIL as long as you declare standard 'runtime managed' methods. However, every time I am adding a 'cil managed' method to the type, I am getting:

**System.TypeLoadException: Illegal definition for runtime implemented delegate method.**

Is it at all possible to extend Delegate/MulticastDelegate?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what do you want to add to the Delegate class by extending it?

Comment: Constructor that takes Target and Method as string (instead of IntPtr).

Comment: Why not just have a static method elsewhere to do the same thing? Sounds an awful lot simpler to me, as well as being less unexpected for whoever maintains the code.

Comment: To extend Jon's suggestion, it seems like you could use a Factory Pattern here and at least abstract the creation of the delegate away from the user and get the calling pattern you want.

Comment: That's how we do stuff in CCC (Completely Cryptic Code), Inc. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not with your own custom code, in C#. From section 10.1.4 of the C# 3.0 spec:

> The direct base class of a class type
>   must not be any of the following
>   types: `System.Array`, `System.Delegate`,
>   `System.MulticastDelegate`, `System.Enum`,
>   or `System.ValueType`. Furthermore, a
>   generic class declaration cannot use
>   `System.Attribute` as a direct or
>   indirect base class.

However, every time you create a delegate type, that automatically derives from `MulticastDelegate`.

From [ECMA-335](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-335.htm), section 8.9.3:

> While, for the most part, delegates
>   appear to be simply another kind of
>   user-defined class, they are tightly
>   controlled. The implementations of the
>   methods are provided by the VES, not
>   user code. The only additional members
>   that can be defined on delegate types
>   are static or instance methods.

That sounds like it's prohibiting constructors. I'd use a static method in a normal type instead, personally.

Answer (score 2):

You may be interested in looking at the following [post](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/653034.aspx) from Rick Strahl where he compares different methods of dynamic delegate creation.